# Install Hue without Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue

Has anyone tried/succeeded in installing Hue on Hadoop without Cloudera?

I have gotten to a point where I can reliably reproduce a hadoop cluster with hbase and hive and can set it all up in about 15 minutes. I'd love to have Hue along with all this without having to go back and redo my setup with Cloudera.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Checkout slides #19 & #5, Hue is getting everywhere and is compatible with Hadoop 0.20 / 1.2.0 / 2.2.0: http://gethue.com/hue-goes-to-paris-hug-france/

Hue has tarball releases [releases](http://gethue.com/category/release/) that you are free to install. You can also simply clone the source code (Hue is open source and Apache Licenced) github: https://github.com/cloudera/hue and build the branch you want.

Upstream documentation is [here](http://cloudera.github.io/hue/docs-3.5.0/index.html) or CDH's one [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_hue_installation.html).

Hue is also packaged in [BigTop](http://bigtop.apache.org/) (and so based on Vanilla Hadoop).

Hue is a Web Server (Django based) which acts as a view on top of Hadoop. So Hue just needs to be installed and then configured by adding the hosts of NameNode, JobTracker, Resource Manager, Oozie, HiveServer... etc in its hue.ini.

Also, as detailed on the [gehue.com/releases](http://gethue.com/category/release/), the version you need might depend on your Hive version.

Notice that without Cloudera's distribution your mileage might vary but feel free to chime-in on the Hue [user-list](http://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/group/hue-user) or [gethue.com](http://gethue.com) ;)

We are also seeing for improving Hue setup with Amazon AWS/EMR!

Comment: gethue.com has now guides for many distributions in its 'Download' and 'Configure'  menu

Comment: the links provided in the above answer goes to tumblr site. You need to fix them.

Answer (score 2):

To build and run hue 3.6.0 with apache hadoop 2.4.1

1. git clone https://github.com/cloudera/hue.git    (Notice! releases/tag/release-3.6.0 is unstable, It's better to build from latest master. I built from Aug 7, 87d6b2da1 - it's stable)
2. cd hue
3. `$ vi maven/pom.xml`
4. change hadoop.version to 2.4.1
5. replace hadoop-core with hadoop-common
6. set hadoop-test version to 1.2.1
7. remove files which need hadoop mr1
8. `$ rm desktop/libs/hadoop/java/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ThriftJobTrackerPlugin.java`
9. `$ rm desktop/libs/hadoop/java/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/thriftfs/ThriftJobTrackerPlugin.java`
10. build hue    `$ make apps`
11. configure hue  `$ vi desktop/conf/pseudo-distributed.ini`
12. run hue server in dev mode   `$ build/env/bin/hue runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: added my instruction to github cloudera hue wiki https://github.com/cloudera/hue/wiki

Comment: If you only use hive, it's fine. But if you want to the other tools, it's not enough. The Hue repo on github does not include oozie. Without Oozie, hue can not connect with pig, hbase, spark and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Hue manual installation steps](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap-hue.html) from Hortonworks documentation, it will take you step-by-step on how to do it manually.

Comment: Doesn't it assume that HDP repo (yum install hue) has to be configured. I think the original query was about installing Hue on Apache Hadoop and not on 3rd party Hadoop like Cloudera/HortonWorks.

Comment: Yes, this does assume that HDP is configured, however you can skip that and grab the rpm-s yourself and continue with the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Quote: "...without Cloudera's distribution your mileage might vary...."

Indeed, it *will* vary A LOT! It would seem that the following is quite true:

Per the install giude:
http://cloudera.github.io/hue/docs-2.0.1/manual.html#_install_hue

NOTE:
Hue requires the Hadoop contained in Cloudera’s Distribution including Apache Hadoop (CDH), version 3 update 4 or later.

I've tried it and have run into walls with Hue trying to connect to Hive, Pig and OOZIE.

At this stage - from my experience at least - Hue will NOT run on a standard Apache Hadoop installation using standard Apache tools like Hive and Pig. It must be a vintage of Cloudera’s Distribution.

If anyone has any other (positive) experiences installing Hue outside of the Cloudera’s Distribution, I'd be quite interested to hear about them...