# Is there any webapp for hbase data visualization

Tags: web-services, hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I want to view my data of hbase through browser. Is there any tool for this purpose so that I can view, manipulate data and get some result. Hbase shell interface is not easy to understand as I am new to hbase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can choose what distribution to use, I'll recommend you [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/home.html). There is a good [hbase data browser](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-manage-hbase-data-via-hue/) inside Hue. It supports **filtering** by families/columns and **search** in hbase table.

[image]

Also, it is possible to **add** data in cells

[image]

And **edit** it

[image: Edit data]

Comment: I am using apache hadoop and how to use hue for it

Comment: I habe a running cluster and want to use HUE so how to do it

Comment: @user3454410 [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579357/install-hue-without-cloudera) will be helpful